# Edit .drw file unicode text in python

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

I am reading in the text from a .drw file (exported from power flow software) and have to search and replace parts of the text within the file. The .drw file looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdrGy.png). After running the following code, the text is replaced properly, but the unicode text is printed completely different to the original file and looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPF6m.png). I need these to look identical.

```
if int(Site.NoCbs)==4: #No Mains Circuit Breaker
                f = open('2fuse_4pump_4cb.drw', 'r+', encoding = 'utf8', errors = 'ignore')
                new_1line = open('2fuse_4pump_4cb_new.txt', 'w')

New_list = [] #new 1 line to be edited
    for line in f:
        New_list.append(line)
    print(New_list)

if int(Site.NoCbs)==4:
        for cb1b in range(0, len(New_list)):
            New_list[cb1b] = New_list[cb1b].replace('PCB1', CircuitBreaker.equipID[0])
        for cb2b in range(0, len(New_list)):
            New_list[cb2b] = New_list[cb2b].replace('PCB2', CircuitBreaker.equipID[1])
        for cb3 in range(0, len(New_list)):
            New_list[cb3] = New_list[cb3].replace('PCB3', CircuitBreaker.equipID[2])
        for cb4 in range(0, len(New_list)):
            New_list[cb4] = New_list[cb4].replace('PCB4', CircuitBreaker.equipID[3])

for j in New_list:
        new_1line.write("%s"%j)
    new_1line.close()
```

Comment: This appears to be a binary file, which means you need to open it as binary then search for the strings yourself. And don't be surprised if it doesn't work at all, especially if your replacement strings are a different size.

Comment: i tried this and it worked but when i wrote the new file it was written in binary. How can i encode the binary to look like the orginal file?

Comment: Open both the input and output as binary. Start by coding a simple copy that makes no changes to the file; once that's working, the rest will be easier.

Comment: thankyou so much. All working fine now